# _update_by_query does not update all matched documents

Tags: elasticsearch

there are total 37 documents matched the query:
[image: query]

update with same query:
[image: update by query]
result show updated 37 documents. I think this means all productName with productId=72337 are updated to new productName `1`.

then query agagin(same condition):
[image: query again]
productName is not updated.

Actually there is only one document is updated to new productName, the other 36 are not updated.
Why?

Comment: es version is 7.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the reason. `productId` is String in document, it is defined as `keyword` in mapping, change it to String in script works.